# Changes in pH when adding substances other than acids or bases

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry

If I start out with 100 mM acetic acid, what substance (to a final concentration of 1 M) could I add to change the pH considerably? I was thinking of NaCl or ethanol or acetone. Substances added should not be acids or bases, i.e. a 1 M solution of them should have a pH close to neutral. I'm asking because I am trying to create a demonstration on how pH calculations are just approximations under non-ideal conditions.

The acetic acid should not undergo an chemical reaction (other than acid/base). I would use a pH meter to monitor the pH. I would have a control where I increase the volume to match the experiment where I add a substance that influences the pH (or dissolve the substance in 100 mM acetic acid to keep the acetic acid concentration constant).

I am looking for changes in pH based on non-ideal behavior. The concentration of acetic acid should remain the same, and there should not be any neutralization reaction. In other words, the calculate pH should stay at 2.87 (assuming ideal conditions) while the measured pH would change.

Comment: This is an interesting question. The easiest way is to the change the properties of the solvent. Add something like DMSO.

Comment: If your initial solvent is water, the easiest to increase the concentration of aceitic acid and, therefore, increase the pH would be to somehow decrease the volume of water. Possibly look for a way to evaporate water. Distilling the solution might be tricky since the boiling point of acetic acid and water are close (118 celsius). Another way might be to use a dehydrating agent to eliminate water. The best dehydrating agent I can think of are all strong acids (sulfuric and phosphoric). However, hot aluminum oxide might also work (if it doesn't have any side reactions with aceitic acid).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but probably some neutral buffer or a zwitterion with $\mathrm{pI}$ close to neutral would satisfy the requirements as either of those separately a) would have a pH close to neutral; b) effectively "capture" protons and keep $\mathrm{pH}$ close to 7.

Comment: It becomes harder and harder to make suggestions as you edit the question:) Since  changing the concentration of acetic acid is not allowed, should the system remain homogeneous, e.g. is it allowed to add a secondary phase (such as non-mixing organic solvent or solid) while measuring the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the aqueous one?

Comment: @andselisk I appreciate the thoughtful comments, you are helping me to write a better question. Adding a second phase would be fine (there is a second phase already - air - and it might get me into trouble if CO2 starts dissolving in my solution).

Comment: A bit different from what you're asking, but how about a demo of NaOH absorbing water from the atmosphere?  A simple one would be to make up a 1.0M solution in a 1.000L volumetric the night before the demo, then have the demo being about estimating the volume difference (based on the neck diameter and height above the volumetric mark) and hence the pH difference.  In this case, the demo is less about added solutes, and more about the property of one solute and how that affects the solution requiring standardization.

Comment: Here's another idea: what about adding or removing heat (i.e. showing the temperature dependency of kw)?  It's not the exact scenario you ask for, but, in terms of showing that pH is based on ideal conditions, it should make the students question the validity of the kw = 1E-14 assumption.

Comment: You question sounds like you really misunderstood a lot of the science about pH. The pH is DEFINED according to the concentration of H+/OH-, so if there is a discrepancy between your prediction and reality, then your prediction is wrong. Also "substances added should not be acids or bases" does not make sense because all substances are acids or bases when compared to another substance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alcohol or acetone but they are slightly acidic (though much less so than acetic acid; also alcohols react to form esters). Now effects from acidic nature can't completely avoided as even a molecule as non-acidic as methane still has a pka of 50. I think an aliphatic ether such as tetrahydrofuran (THF) or diethylether would be the best substance to add as the ethers are only very slightly basic and are miscible with water.

More simply:

> what substance could I add to change the pH considerably?

Why does it have to be a substance? The $K_\mathrm w = 10^{14}$ at $\pu{25^\circ C}$. If you add heat the $K_\mathrm w$ will increase and thus the pH will increase.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is addition of the neutral concentrated solution of some salt.

It will affect activity coefficients of the conjugated acids/bases.

E.g., if a phosphate buffer is used, $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ would be affected more then $\ce{H2PO4-}$.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_activity:

> When a 0.1 M hydrochloric acid solution containing methyl green indicator is added to a 5 M solution of magnesium chloride, the color of the indicator changes from green to yellow—indicating increasing acidity—when in fact the acid has been diluted. Although at low ionic strength (< 0.1 M) the activity coefficient approaches unity, this coefficient can actually increase with ionic strength in a high ionic strength regime. For hydrochloric acid solutions, the minimum is around 0.4 M.

So you mix a solution with a pH of about 1 with a neutral salt solution, and the solution gets more acidic.